# CSS selector for table with particular TD

Tags: css

I have two tables with same class

```
<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='pppagetitle'>A Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='ppinstance'>Another Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but want to select only the one with td class pppagetitle (!) - any pointers?

Comment: There is a similar post here that might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: Justed edited/specified the question: In my real HTML there are many tables all with *class pp*, and I want to select only certain ones, namely the ones containing data with td *class pppagetitle*. And, I can't edit the html, I'll need an external CSS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jason Groulx's pointer on a previous post with a very [elaborate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) regarding this issue solved things for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
.pp > .pppagetitle {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='pppagetitle'>A Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='ppinstance'>Another Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.pp:nth-child(1){background:green;}
```

But this isn't well supported (doesn't work in IE8 and below)

Alternatively put the tables in a container and use

```
:first-child
```

Example:

```html
<style>
    .container > .pp:first-child{background:green;}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <table class="pp"></table>
    <table class="pp"></table>
</div>
```

for more documentation: [Quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts, assuming they share a parent, would be:

```
table.pp:first-child
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uTWKG/).

But this will, and *can*, only select the particular `table` (with that class) if it's the first-child of its parent element.

There is no `:first-of-class()` selector (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class and select only the table desired:

```
<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='pppagetitle anotherClass'>A Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='pp' >
  <tr class='pp'>
    <td class='ppinstance'>Another Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`table.pp:first-child`

supported in ie7+

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
table.pp:first-child
```

or

```
table.pp:nth-of-type(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo selector